# 6 x 2048 faster than 3 x 4096 DDR3 triple channel memory modules?

Tags: memory, speed, ddr3, triple-channel

Considering same timings, brand and technology triple channel RAM memory modules would:
6 x 2048 MB modules be faster than 3 x 4096 MB modules ?

Comment: "It depends"...  Memory controller/processor/chipset all have a lot to do with it.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on CPU and memory mhz, however if you are running a single processor, 3x4GB will be better than 6x2GB. If you had 2 CPU's (not 2 cores), it would be better to use 6x2GB.

Comment: Not that I doubt you. But why is it faster with 6x2GB if you have 2 cpu's. I thought they used the same memory bus.

Comment: @Nifle - Modern multi-processor systems have separate memory controllers for each CPU. In modern Intel and AMD designs, the memory controller is actually on the CPU. This means there is three channels per socket.

Comment: @MarkM absolutely right! (:

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a specific CPU, chipset, etc. Some chipsets are applying slower memory timings when all memory slots are populated, so according to my knowledge 3x4GB will be faster.